# Stop a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, real-time

I'm taking some real time data through sockets and segregating and plotting a parameter in tkinter GUI. It works fine. I'm threading it so I can create a stop button in parallel to break from an infinite while loop, but it's not working. The GUI opens and as soon as I hit start, it closes. It doesn't even function. How do I manage to create a stop button in such a case where anything else is not hindered?

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from random import randint  
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
import time 
import threading
import datetime as dt


IP = "172.16.22.113"
PORT = 30000
addr = (IP,PORT)

soc = socket.socket()
print("Socket created")

soc.connect(addr)

stop = 0

def function():
    if Checkbutton1.get():
        Check1 = True
    else:
        Check1 = False
    if Checkbutton2.get():
        Check2 = True
    else:
        Check2 = False
    data_points(Check1, Check2) 
        
def start_thread():
    global stop
    stop=0
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=function)
    t1.start()
    
def stop():
    global stop
    stop=1
    
def data_points(Check1, Check2):
    first_step=0
    df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Chan','Doppler','Code','C_N0','SNR','Track','Stat','Config','X'])
    while True:
        data = soc.recv(4096).decode()
        Chan = []
        Doppler = []
        Code = []
        C_N0 = []
        SNR = []
        Track = []
        Stat = []
        Config = []
        X_axis =  []
        xx = []
        
        a = data.split_lines()
        for line in a:
            if (line=="BEGIN, AUTO CHANSTATE"):
                i = a.index(line)
                time=i+2
                x_as = a[time].split[3]
                t=i+3
                for p in range(28):
                    t+=1
                    Chan.append(int(a[t].split()[1]))
                    Doppler.append(float(a[t].split()[2]))
                    Code.append(float(a[t].split()[3]))
                    C_N0.append(float(a[t].split()[4]))
                    Track.append(float(a[t].split()[5]))
                    Stat.append(a[t].split()[6])
                    Config.append(a[t].split()[7])
                    xx.append(first_step)
                    
                df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Chan,Doppler,Code,C_N0,SNR,Track,Stat,Config,xx)), columns=['Chan','Doppler','Code','C_N0','SNR','Track','Stat','Config','X'])
                Chan_2 = df[df["Chan"]==2]
                
                first_step=first_step+1
                
                if(Check1==True):
                    ax1=fig.add_subplot(321)
                    ax1.cla() 
                    ax1.grid() 
                    ax1=set_xlabel("Time")
                    ax1=set_ylabel("C_N0")
                    ax1.plot(Chan_2["X"], Chan_2["C_N0"], marker='o', color='orange')
                    graph.draw()

                if(Check2==True):
                    ax2=fig.add_subplot(322)
                    ax2.cla() 
                    ax2.grid() 
                    ax2=set_xlabel("Time")
                    ax2=set_ylabel("Dopp")
                    ax2.plot(Chan_2["x"], Chan_2["Doppler"], marker='o', color='orange')
                    graph.draw() 
                    
                if stop==1:
                    break
                
new_window=' '

def openwindow():
    global new_window
    global Checkbutton1
    global Checkbutton2
    global fig
    global graph
    global start
    
    new_window=Toplevel(root)
    new_window.geometry(1000x700)
    lbl=Label(new_window, text="Window corresponds to channel")
    
    fig=Figure()
    
    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root) 
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)
    
    C_N0_plot=Checkbutton(new_window, text="C_N0 vs time", variable=Checkbutton1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2)
    C_N0_plot.place(x=700,100)
    
    Dopp_plot=Checkbutton(new_window, text="Doppler vs time", variable=Checkbutton2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2)
    Dopp_plot.place(x=700,100)

    start = Button(new_window, text="Start", command=start_thread, bg="red", fg="white") 
    start.pack()
    stop = Button(new_window, text="Stop", command=stop) 
    stop.pack()
                
root = Tk() 
root.config(background='white') 
root.geometry.("500x500") 
 
btn=Button(root,text="Open new window", command=openwindow)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global stop()` should be `global stop` inside `stop()`. However avoid having same name for function and variable.

Comment: @acw1668 My bad. It was a typo while posting the question. And I tried changing the function name too, it still didn't work and I had to forcibly stop it while the Tkinter went in not responding state. Can you help me out with this by any means?

Comment: You can bind the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol, to a function and make that function destroy the root window, merge all threads, and `sys.exit()`. I am not very familiar with the use of threads though, so I am not sure of it's working, but it can definitely be tried.

Comment: `if stop==1: break` is inside `if (line=="BEGIN, AUTO CHANSTATE"):`, so if the condition is never `True`, the while loop will not be terminated.  I suggest to put `if stop==1: break` outside the if block and change `while True` to `while stop != 1`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks. It did solve my problem to an extent.